# Given two metric, $d_1$ dominates $d_2$ and $X$ is complete w.r.t. $d_1$, then $(X, d_1)$ is complete, then $(X, d_2)$ is complete?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a space $X$ and metric $d_1, d_2$, suppose $d_1 \leq d_2$. Also suppose $(X, d_1)$ is complete. Then, is it true that $(X, d_2)$ is complete?

Attempt: Take Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $(X, d_2)$. Then, the sequence is Cauchy in $(X, d_1)$. Hence, $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ in $(X, d_1)$. I am stuck here since I cannot conclude $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ w.r.t. $d_2$.

Comment: I suspect that an extra condition is needed. Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2231589/75923) can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=\{2^{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and let $d_2$ be the usual Euclidean metric on $X$. (Note that $0\in\Bbb N$.) Define a metric $d_1$ on $X$ as follows:

$$d_1(2^{-m},2^{-n})=\begin{cases}
|2^{-m}-2^{-n}|,&\text{if }m=n\text{ or }m\ne 0\ne n\\
2^{-m},&\text{if }n=0\\
2^{-n},&\text{if }m=0\,.
\end{cases}$$

> It’s easy to check that $d_1$ is a metric: either directly or by observing that it is simply the Euclidean metric on $\{0\}\cup\{2^{-n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ transferred to $X$ by the bijection $h$ defined by setting
>
> $$h(y)=\begin{cases}
> y,&\text{if }y\ne 0\\
> 1,&\text{if }y=0\,.
> \end{cases}$$

Clearly $d_1(2^{-m},2^{-n})\le d_2(2^{-m},2^{-n})$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb N$, and $\langle X,d_1\rangle$ is compact, so it is complete, but $\langle 2^{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\langle X,d_2\rangle$ that does not converge in $\langle X,d_2\rangle$.

As **drhab** suggested in the comments, you need an extra hypothesis in order to be able to conclude that $\langle X,d_2\rangle$ is complete, and one that works is the hypothesis that for each $x\in X$ and $r>0$, the closed $d_2$-ball $\{y\in X:d_2(x,y)\le r\}$ is also closed in the metric $d_1$; see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231589/if-d-1x-y-leq-d-2x-y-and-all-d-2-closed-balls-in-m-are-also-d-1-clo).